# wildcard DNS A record for Azure Reserved Website

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have setup a wildcard A record so *.mydomain.com resolves to the fixed IP address of my reserved WAWS. I have also set up a few test a and cname records for various subdomains.

The guide [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/) explicitly mentions wildcard a records:

> A record
>
> With an A record, you map a domain (e.g., contoso.com or
>   www.contoso.com) or a wildcard domain (e.g., *.contoso.com) to the
>   single public IP address of a deployment within a Windows Azure web
>   site.
>
> The main benefit of this approach over using CNAMEs is that you can
>   map root domains (e.g., contoso.com) and wildcard domains (e.g.,
>   *.contoso.com), in addition to subdomains (e.g., www.contoso.com).

In the Azure portal, I am able to add various domains which get validated before being accepted. I can add the root mydomain.com plus any explicit a and c subdomains eg test.mydomain.com. Navigating to mydomain.com, www.mydomain.com and test.mydomain.com all work fine but if I try something.mydomain.com where I have not explicitly set this up, I get a 404.

something.mydomain.com resolves to the correct IP but just does not work. When using a wildcard a record, what do I need to configure in azure to get it working?

mydomain.com is already there but does not seem to allow just any subdomain

*.mydomain.com is not accepted

Even explicitly trying to add each required subdomain (eg something.mydomain.com) does not seem to work as the validation fails (unless I create a separate DNS record for each subdomain which defeats the purpose of the wildcard).

I am at a loss as to how to proceed. Given the mention of wildcard domains in the windowsazure.com article mentioned above, it seems as though they should be supported but in that same article, there is a [comment](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/#comment-700346954) stating that they are not supported and I certainly have not manage to get it working so far.

Any idea whether this is possible right now?

Comment: Wildcard A records certainly work for Cloud Services as I went through a similar process a few weeks back. Not sure about WAWS?? Does your DNS server support wildcard CNAMES?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wilcard domains aren't supported by WAWS currently.  Its in the works for now.

Comment: thanks. would be nice if the doc I mentioned was updated to remove the reference to them.

Comment: I've been using wildcard domain records *.mydomain.com since April and they're working fine. Maybe the support was now enabled recently?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, most documentation on Azure is out of date, for example the pages about CDN. 
It's to bad that you can't rely on whats written.

I assume there's been no change to this wildcard matter since March?

Comment: I have not seen any announcements. I ended up moving to a web role because the cost of having multiple SSL certs on WAWS was far more expensive.